# How can I generate combinations like below using recursive javascript?

Tags: javascript

Apologies, I am a newbie and I'm having trouble wording my question enough so I can search for it here, I tried but I couldn't find the answer using my search terms.

Given 1. a number length of array and 2. an array of different numbers how can I have combination like this through recursion?

```
const number_of_combinations = 4; // the arrays must be 4 in length
const combinations = [1,2,3];

// answer 
// [1,1,1,1]
// [1,1,1,2]
// [1,1,1,3]
// [1,1,2,1]
// [1,1,2,2]
// [1,1,2,3]
// etc....
```

p.s. If you can point me to a duplicate or answer I will delete this question right away, I know this must be something that's already been answered here.

Comment: Iterate from 0 to 4, push a new item to an empty array containing one of the combination items.

Comment: combinations or permutations?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a recursive solution?

Comment: @JonasWilms sorry, what is the difference? the resulting array has to be all different

Comment: @whiterook6 yes, is it easier if it's not?

Comment: When doing recursion, figure out the solution for the base case N=1. Then figure out how you combine a case with the next simpler case.

Comment: This is a duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543936/combination-with-repetition

Comment: @MarcoCab: Even if this post is a duplicate, there's no need to delete it! Usually duplicates (after mod approval) will close the post and show a "This post already has answers here: ..." for others when they stumble apon the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination with repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543936/combination-with-repetition)

Comment: Ah, actually it's already in the question, you want permutation as the order matters ([1,1,1,2] and [1,1,2,1])

Comment: @Marco Cab easier or not depends but that's fine. To solve a recursive problem like this, you have to first think of how to break the problem into smaller parts then assemble them. For example, what are the solutions for this problem when you need only one item? I'd guess the array would look like [1, 2, 3]. Then figure out how to use that base case to build the solutions for one more: something + [1, 2, 3].

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It did answer the question, it's ok to leave this here or should I delete this question?

Comment: It's okay to leave it, might help future googler's to find this :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great usecase for a recursive generator function:

```
  function* combine(source, length, prev = []) {
    if(prev.length >= length) {
       yield prev;
       return;
    }

    for(const el of source) {
       yield* combine(source, length, [...prev, el]);
    }
 }

 const result = [...combine([1, 2, 3], 4)];
```

Comment: I always get confused seeing `function *` (coming from a C++ background) and I think "Returns a pointer to a function? *What?* oh wait it's a yield thingy"